# running python on heroku terminal

Tags: python, heroku

I'm trying to run python on Heroku terminal. I have done it many times before and it working well. But today, when I enter:

```
heroku run python
```

on the terminal, It not show a python terminal but give me this error :

```
 ! Timeout awaiting dyno, see https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/one-off-dynos#timeout-awaiting-process
```

Comment: What is the output of this command `telnet rendezvous.runtime.heroku.com 5000`

Comment: I type in : heroku run python telnet rendezvous.runtime.heroku.com 5000. And having the same problem

Comment: No please try running `telnet rendezvous.runtime.heroku.com 5000` no `heroku run`

Comment: yeah, I think so cause now I'm using library intranet, so it may block the connection